# Do asynchronous HTTP requests in UIWebView really spawn new threads or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading, uiwebview

I'm working on a hybrid project that involves loading content asynchronously in a UIWebView.

We are thinking about where to do the downloading of content.

One option would be doing the asynchronous loading inside the UIWebView:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://hostname.com/login",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: login_info,
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (xhr) {}
})
```

Second option is in native code via the Javascript bridge:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "myprotocol://login",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: login_info,
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (xhr) {}
})
```

catch it:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
if([self containsCustomProtocol:request]) {
    //do native call
    return NO;
}
```

and then call this on return on main thread:

```
[this.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName()"];
```

What would be best? No spawning  of threads with first, yes with the second method, or does it not matter?

Comment: It seems like you could set `async:false` in the second case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC all web requests are done on a specific web loading GCD queue. You can easily test that by firing off several long durarion requests and then halting the app in debugger. Then check the threads you see.

If you look at the queue mode then you should only one queue named such. In thread mode you might see multiple threads because GCD uses and reuses threads to execute blocks on GCD the most efficient way.

Internally webviews also use NSURLLoading and NSURLProtocol classes. So there should be IMHO no conceivable advantage of either your approaches.

If you want some control over the traffic from outside the web view you can get that by registering your own http protocol handler(or even your own scheme) or by overriding the NSURLCache used by the web view. The cache is accessed on a single thread, while NSURLProtocol works with multiple operations in parallel, probably multithreaded.